# Simple drag`n`drop in Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash, image, drag, builder

I have a very simple question, but I can not find solutions to it. I need to add multiple images that can be moved with the mouse. This components NumericStapper must be in the group with the image and move together.

http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/9341/323.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found a reference
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_1.html